# How would I extract the value for the key eventAction?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using `REGEXEXTRACT` in Google sheets, and I need to extract the value of the key eventAction. In the example below, the value = **Made searchable**.

> {"parentFolderId":"1112","type":"ua","fingerprint":"1671037591717","consentSettings":{"consentStatus":"notSet"},"containerId":"573184","accountId":"372859","name":"Job
> Apply - Profile Made
> Searchable","tagId":"990","monitoringMetadata":{"type":"map"},"parameter":[{"type":"boolean","value":"false","key":"nonInteraction"},{"type":"boolean","value":"false","key":"overrideGaSettings"},{"type":"template","value":"Jobs","key":"eventCategory"},{"type":"template","value":"TRACK_EVENT","key":"trackType"},{"type":"template","value":"{{Google
> Analytics Setting - EFC Production
> GA}}","key":"gaSettings"},{"type":"template","value":"**Made
> searchable**","key":"eventAction"}],"tagFiringOption":"unlimited","firingTriggerId":["989"]}

I've tried multiple combinations of regex, but haven't been able to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following formula to get the result: **Made searchable**

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,".*""(.*)"",""key"":""eventAction")
```

*(**Do** adjust the formula according to your ranges and locale)**

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
=regexextract(substitute(A1,"""",""),":([^:]*)\,key:eventAction")
```

[image]